# How to remove an entry from memDB in GO

Tags: go, memdb

I am doing something like this with [`github.com/hashicorp/go-memdb`](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-memdb):

```
// Create a sample struct
type Person struct {
    Email string
    Name  string
    Age   int
}

// Create the DB schema
schema := &memdb.DBSchema{
    Tables: map[string]*memdb.TableSchema{
        "person": &memdb.TableSchema{
            Name: "person",
            Indexes: map[string]*memdb.IndexSchema{
                "id": &memdb.IndexSchema{
                    Name:    "id",
                    Unique:  true,
                    Indexer: &memdb.StringFieldIndex{Field: "Email"},
                },
                "age": &memdb.IndexSchema{
                    Name:    "age",
                    Unique:  false,
                    Indexer: &memdb.IntFieldIndex{Field: "Age"},
                },
            },
        },
    },
}

// Create a new data base
db, err := memdb.NewMemDB(schema)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// Create a write transaction
txn := db.Txn(true)

// Insert some people
people := []*Person{
    &Person{"joe@aol.com", "Joe", 30},
    &Person{"lucy@aol.com", "Lucy", 35},
    &Person{"tariq@aol.com", "Tariq", 21},
    &Person{"dorothy@aol.com", "Dorothy", 53},
}
for _, p := range people {
    if err := txn.Insert("person", p); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

// Commit the transaction
txn.Commit()
```

My question is how do I remove `joe@aol.com` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Txn.Delete`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/go-memdb#Txn.Delete) by passing an object with the unique index field set to the desired value.

Based on your schema, the unique index is associated to the struct `Email` field, so pass to `Delete` a `Person` struct with that field (it doesn't have to be a pointer):

```
// new write tx
deltxn := db.Txn(true)
err = deltxn.Delete("person", Person{Email: "joe@aol.com"})
```

If you want to delete multiple entries, use [`Txn.DeleteAll`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/go-memdb#Txn.DeleteAll) and pass the table name, the index name and a filter value. It returns the number of deleted entries:

```
deltxn = db.Txn(true)
// deleting all entries with age=30
d, err = txn.DeleteAll("person", "age", 30)
// d is 1
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/b-Tl5Nntdjm